# Velocity does not replace Template's variables with VelocityContext

Tags: java, velocity

I'm new to Velocity and found it was strange that template's variables did not be replaced by the value I put into the VelocityContext.

The code is like this.

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;

public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]){
    People XiaoMing=new People("XiaoMing", 11);
    VelocityEngine engine=new VelocityEngine();
    Template template=engine.getTemplate("/src/main/java/VMTemplate.vm");
    VelocityContext context=new VelocityContext();
    context.put("People", XiaoMing);
    StringWriter sw=new StringWriter(10000);
    template.merge(context, sw);
    System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }
}

class People{
  private String name;
  private int age;
  public People(String name,int age){
      this.name=name;
      this.age=age;
  }

  public String getName(){
      return name;
  }

  public int getAge(){
      return age;
   }
}
```

The template is shown below.

```
#set($Name=$People.getName())
#set($Age=$People.getAge())

He is a $Age years old guy,and his name is $Name.
```

I do not know what is going wrong. Could you find out for me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Tell us what you have done/tried. No we cannot find out for you, but we can help you find out

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Actually, I want the string "$People" in the template be replaced by variable "XiaoMing". The ideal output will be this:        He is a 11 years old guy,and his name is XiaoMing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason why the object doesn't be replaced in template.

Object can be parsed by Velocity **only** when it is **public**.
Thus I just need to create a public class named Xiaoming.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax after you have some template is

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("Name", XiaoMing.getName());
```

Xiaoming is a people object, and not a string.

Comment: Thank you! It works. But I am still confused that why I cannot input an object into the VelocityContext?

Comment: Think about what an object is. It's a collection of data. How does one print an object (not an attribute of an object)? What happens when you do System.out.println(XiaoMing) ?

Comment: Well, actually VelocityContext can accept an object. The keypoint I found was that the object must be public! If I create a public object, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue.
If you use a *custom field*, you do not need a *context provider*.
Instead, override AbstractCustomFieldType's [getVelocityParameters()](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.0.9/com/atlassian/jira/issue/customfields/impl/AbstractCustomFieldType.html#getVelocityParameters-com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue-com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField-com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.layout.field.FieldLayoutItem-), it returns a map.

One more gotcha is that whitespace cannot precede `#` that starts `#foreach`, etc., no idea why.